# Query database using select options rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to implement a sort ability on a show page and I have no idea of how to approach it. I am querying dosage on a patient show page. I want to use ajax/ jQuery as a user will only be changing one section of the page, and I don't want it to reload.

```
<%= widget('fas fa-tag', 'Dosage').actions do %>
      <%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([["Default", 1],["Current", 2],["Finished", 3]], params[:option] ), id: "select") %>
    <% end.thead do %>
      <th>Drug</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    <% end.table(patient.dosages.with_items_any, responsive: false, limit: 10, total: patient.dosages.count, more_path: dosages_path(dosages_search_id: 'all', dosage_search: {query: {all_fields: "patient_id:#{patient.id}"}}, commit: "Search")
       ) do |dose| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= typed_pretty_link_to dose %></td>
        <td><%= truncate(dose.subject, length: 55) %></td>
        <td><%= l dose.created_at.to_date %></td>
        <td><%= dose.status %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View', dosage_path(dose.id) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end if allow?('dosages-index') %>
```

I added the select tag to be able to have a dropdown option, so that a user can query the list with the options `Default` which all will query the dosage in descending order, `Current` will query dosages with the status `Current` and `Finished` will query with the status `Finished`. My controller queries Patients:

```
Patient.find(params[:id])
```

Any help or direction will be appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Comment: why not use a datatable?

Comment: I'm already querying from the database, I just want to sort them differently, either by status or descending order

Comment: What datatable library are you using? most of the datatables already have sorting capabilities.

Comment: Filterrific has some really nice options for rails views sorting. https://github.com/jhund/filterrific